# How to set the default sound in twilio for answering calls via a mobile browser to headphones?

Tags: c#, twilio

If I receive a call on a mobile browser using Twilio while my headphones are not connected to my device the default sound is coming from my speakers.

By default I want the sound to come from my headphones. Either my headphones are connected OR not!

Comment: So you want no sound if no headphones are connected?

Comment: No by default when we recieve a call on phone and if no headphones connected sound comes from ear phone not speaker. In my case when we receive call on browser on phone sound comes from speaker i want it to come from ear phone